# Stack CSS Grid element without media queries

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm looking to stack 2 columns once they get too "squished" in the viewport using CSS grid.

Right now I have:

```
<style>
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 260px;
    grid-gap: 1em;

}
@media only screen and (min-width:600px) {
  .grid {
     grid-template-columns: 100% 100%;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="grid">
    <main>More stuff here...</main>
    <aside>Stuff inside here...</aside>
</div>
```

The columns just seem to grow to 100% in width rather than stacking. Is there a way to do this without the media query?

Comment: if it is only about to stack everithing, just reset display:grid to display:block ....

Comment: Please post enough code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: With `display:flex` you can do this: https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/vrgaVr (resize page) .... is that the effect you were after?

Answer (score 0):

Use flex property instead of grid

```
.grid{
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you are looking for an automatic number of columns.

The syntax **repeat** in grid-template-columns allows for the keyword *auto-fit*. When using this keyword, the column count will be adjusted so that the max column width will not overflow the grid width.

In the snippet, setting a max width of 300px makes the grid have only 1 column when it's size is 550px:

```css
.grid{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(auto, 300px));
    grid-gap: 1em;
    border: solid 1px black;
    margin: 10px;
}

#grid1 {
  width: 550px;
}

#grid1 {
  width: 650px;
}

main {
    background-color: yellow;
}

aside {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid" id="grid1">
    <main>More stuff here...</main>
    <aside>Stuff inside here...</aside>
</div>
<div class="grid" id="grid2">
    <main>More stuff here...</main>
    <aside>Stuff inside here...</aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Yes we can achieve it using `flex box`**

Here is the sample piece of code where we can wrap our elements to new line when it reaches certain width without writing any external media queries.

Only we need to do is like apply the below properties in the parent element

`display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: start;`

Even this is one of the advantage of using **flex-box** concept.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: start;
}
.column-1, .column-2, .column-3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5px;
}
.column-1 {
  background: green;
}
.column-2 {
  background: red;
}
.column-3 {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column-1"></div>
  <div class="column-2"></div>
  <div class="column-3"></div>
</div>
```